# Как заменить префикс 'test_' на 'should_' в модульных тестах с примением unittest?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

При использовании библиотеки `unittest`, которая входит в стандартную python библиотеку программист свои тестовые методы вынужден сопровождать `test_`. Мне хочется уточнить, это обязательное требование или же все-таки есть способ заменить его другим, к примеру `should_`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во всех примерах кода ниже буду считать, что доступен класс с тестами:

```
class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_simple(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_complicated(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

    def should_pass(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def should_fail(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

#### Использование поля `testMethodPrefix` в [`TestLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader)

Нашёл способ с использованием ручного запуска через `TestLoader`:

```
import unittest


def run_tests():
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    loader.testMethodPrefix = 'should'   # задаём требуемый префикс тестов
    suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_tests()
```

`TestLoader` имеет поле `testMethodPrefix`, в которое можно записать требуемый префикс тестов. В этом случае будут запущены только методы, которые начинаются с указанной строки.

---

#### Создание собственного `TestLoader`, использующего регулярные выражения для поиска тестов в классе

Как вариант, можно перегрузить класс `TestLoader` и сделать так, чтобы он искал не просто по совпадению префикса, а по регулярному выражению (использовал camelCase для соответствия стилю именования, принятому в unittest):

```
import unittest
import functools
import re


class MyTestLoader(unittest.TestLoader):
    def getTestCaseNames(self, testCaseClass):
        """Return a sorted sequence of method names found within testCaseClass
        """
        def isTestMethod(attrname, testCaseClass=testCaseClass,
                         pattern=self.testMethodPrefix):
            return (re.match(pattern, attrname) and
                    callable(getattr(testCaseClass, attrname)))
        testFnNames = list(filter(isTestMethod, dir(testCaseClass)))
        if self.sortTestMethodsUsing:
            testFnNames.sort(key=functools.cmp_to_key(self.sortTestMethodsUsing))
        return testFnNames


def run_tests():
    loader = MyTestLoader()
    loader.testMethodPrefix = 'should|test'
    suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_tests()
```

Такой загрузчик тестов запустит и стандартные тесты, и тесты, начинающиеся с `should`.

---

#### Использование протокола [`load_tests`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol)

Ещё один способ -- это создать функцию `load_tests`, которая возвращает `TestSuit` для модуля. Если в модуле определена такая функция, то библиотека попробует вызвать её для получения списка тестов:

```
def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    loader.testMethodPrefix = 'should'
    return loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTests)
```

---

Источники:

- [Документация по библиотеке unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html).
- [Документация по `TestLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestLoader).
- [Протокол `load_tests`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol).

Comment: Вот! Как нужно давать ответы! Я хоть и отметил +1, но хочется еще раз выразить благодарность ;)