# Юнит тесты. Что проверять

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, тестирование, junit

Есть маленькое консольное приложение, которое в зависимости от времени и региона пользователя выдает на консоль приветствие разного текста. Также используется Log4j. Приветствия задаются Resources Bundle. Мне нужна ваша помощь в написании Юнит тестов... А именно примеры и какие параметры проверять. В голове только глупые примеры, поэтому нужна ваша помощь в фантазии) Заранее благодарю.
Ссылка на проект на гитхабе.
https://github.com/dimsdale/TestWork

Comment: в том то и дело, что примеры, какими бы они не были глупыми надо постить. Правда по ним будут судить какой вопрос с ними связан. Если нет вопроса, нет и ответа.

Comment: Приведите пример исходного кода. Если вкратце, то вам нужно тестировать логику, которая "в зависимости от времени и региона" выбирает нужный текст.

Comment: @andreycha Ссылку на гитхаб с проектом прикрепил. Можете ознакомиться.

Comment: @Дмитрий, вместо ссылки стоило добавить код, который хотите протестировать непосредственно в вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Основная ваша логика лежит в классе `Greeting` -- его и нужно тестировать. В методе `welcomeUserByLocalization()` у вас выделяются вполне определенные кейсы.

```
public class Greeting {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Greeting.class);
    private static final String GOODNIGHT = "GoodNight";
    private static final String GOODMORNING = "GoodMorning";
    private static final String GOODDAY = "GoodDay";
    private static final String GOODEVENING = "GoodEvening";

    public String welcomeUserByLocalization (Date date, ResourceBundle resourceBundle){
        int hour = date.getHours();

        log.info(String.format("Input date is: '%s', resourceBundle = '%s'" , new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(date), resourceBundle.getLocale()));

        if (hour >= 23 || hour >= 0 && hour <= 5){
            return resourceBundle.getString(GOODNIGHT);
        } else if (hour >= 6 && hour <= 8){
            return resourceBundle.getString(GOODMORNING);
        } else if (hour >= 9 && hour <= 18){
            return resourceBundle.getString(GOODDAY);
        } else if (hour >=19 && hour <=22) {
            return resourceBundle.getString(GOODEVENING);
        } else return null;
    }
}
```

Заглянув в папку с тестами, я увидел, что вы уже написали тесты. Несколько замечаний по ним:

- Некоторые тесты сейчас толком не проверяют логику метода `welcomeUserByLocalization()`. Например, тест `welcomeUserTest2` проверяет только то, что для заданного времени вернулась *какая-то* строка. А нужно проверять, что возвращается строка по ключу "GoodNight". Для этого вы или сверяйте возвращаемое значение со значением из `ResourceBundle`, который вы создаете в тесте, либо мокайте `ResourceBundle` и задавайте свое возвращаемое значение.
- Для каждого из диапазонов желательно проверить как граничные условия (поскольку они у вас нестрогие), так и значение внутри диапазона.
- Именуйте тесты [согласно вашим кейсам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471344/106).

Все остальные вещи (`MessageInit`, `Locale`) я бы не стал тестировать, по крайней мере *пока*. Они очень тривиальны и тесты сводятся по сути к тестированию кода JDK.