# Как избежать дублирования в юнит-тестах?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

Тестирую некоторый алгоритм. Данные для алгоритма хранятся в списке. В итоге у меня получается вот так:

```
@Test
public void testOneDirectModeBestCaseEven(){
    list.add(new Agent(6));
    list.add(new Agent(1));
    list.add(new Agent(2));
    list.add(new Agent(3));
    list.add(new Agent(4));
    list.add(new Agent(5));

    int i = 0;
    while(!list.hasSolution()){
        LeaderElection.solve(list, i++);
    }

    int leaderId = list.getLeaderId();
    assertEquals(6, leaderId);
}

@Test
public void testOneDirectModeBestCaseOdd(){
    list.add(new Agent(5));
    list.add(new Agent(1));
    list.add(new Agent(2));
    list.add(new Agent(3));
    list.add(new Agent(4));

    int i = 0;
    while(!list.hasSolution()){
        LeaderElection.solve(list, i++);
    }

    int leaderId = list.getLeaderId();
    assertEquals(5, leaderId);
}
```

И еще много функций. Получается дублирование в том что я заполняю List в каждом тесте. Но и в `setUp` не вынесешь, потому что заполнять то нужно по-разному для каждого теста.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам могут помочь [параметризованные тесты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471344/106). JUnit их тоже [поддерживает](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests). Приведу код, подробнее почитать можете по ссылкам. (На джаве давно не писал, поэтому скорее всего тут есть ошибки компиляции :))

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class LeaderElectionTests{

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data(){
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{     
                 { <список 1>, <ответ 1> },
                 { <список 2>, <ответ 2> }
           });
    }

    private List list;
    private int expected;

    public LeaderElectionTests(List list, int expected){
        list = input;
        expected = expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void testOneDirectModeBestCase(){
        int i = 0;
        while(!list.hasSolution()){
            LeaderElection.solve(list, i++);
        }

        int leaderId = list.getLeaderId();
        assertEquals(answer, leaderId);
    }
}
```

Однако такой подход нужно использовать только когда вы тестируете *один кейс* на разных наборах входных данных. Если же у вас *разные кейсы*, причем эта разница заложена *непосредственно во входных данных*, то я бы рекомендовал идти по пути отдельных тестов. Это проще для восприятия, потому что так или иначе в названия тестов мы закладываем наши решения и наш опыт, полученные в процессе написания кода. Глядя же на обезличенный список тестовых наборов данных, через месяц уже будет сложно сказать, чем они отличаются между собой.

Судя по коду, ваш объект `list` -- не просто список, он еще содержит в себе некоторую логику. Так что скорее всего разумнее будет остаться с разными тестами и дублирующимися данными, которые на самом деле не дублирующие данные, а разные тест кейсы. Хотя вам должно быть виднее, конечно.